# iOS Passing NSMutableArray between views and load in a table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Well, I have an `NSMutableArray` in a view and I want to pass the value of this array to another view. But I do not want to use the method `[self presentModel view controller ...]` because I just want to display another view when I press another button that I created. The problem is, when I press the button to display the value of the array, the array loses its value, returning empty, but if I use the method `[self presentModel view controller ...]` it returns the value correctly.

CurrentView:

```
@property and @synthesise AnotherViewController *superAnother


AnotherViewController *anView = [[AnotherViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
superAnother.arrayOfTheAnotherView = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayOfTheCurrentView];
```

The Another View:

```
@property and @synthesise NMutableArray *arrayOfTheAnotherView;

NSMultableArray array = [[NSMultableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayOfTheAnotherView];
```

Loading a table view with the array:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: How is the arrayOfTheAnotherView property declared?

Comment: @property(retain, nonatomic) NSMultableArray *arrayOfTheAnotherView;
I'm not using ARC and storyboard

Answer (score 0):

`arrayWithArray` does not create other instances of the collected objects, but another array instance using the same references. If you want to change the datasource objects in the popover or whenever else, you'll want to copy the items with [arrayWithArray:copyItems:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithArray%3acopyItems%3a), of course all the contained objects must conform `NSCopying` protocol to let them to be copied.

Comment: OK, I put the [copyItems: YES] but it did not work, I'm not sure how I'm doing is right. Could you write how it would look with .xib and without ARC?

Comment: @Israel Mesquita then you need to check if `arrayOfTheAnotherView` is `nil` where you are using it to create another array.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of passing an NSMutableArray between view controllers is something along these lines:

- In interface builder add an IBAction to the button in the first view controller
- Add a storyboard segue between the two viewControllers (not from one button to the next view controller but directly between viewControllers
- Give this segue a unique identifier
- In the IBAction from the button in the first view controller add the line

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier"];
- Then in the first view controller you can implement the delegate method:

  ```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


      if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"myIdentifier"]) {

          SecondViewController *con = [segue destinationViewController];
          con.array = self.array;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: i'm not using storyboard, maybe you can help me with the xib

Comment: Hmmm, sorry I'm not very familiar with xib's

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with this code:

You define your `superAnother` property but you're not assigning anything to it. Your code should be like this:

```
self.superAnother = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.superAnother.arrayOfTheAnotherView = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayOfTheCurrentView];
```

Then in your `AnotherViewController.m`:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayOfTheAnotherView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

PS. Of course don't forget to release them if you're not using ARC

Comment: I tried to put this but I'm not using ARC, I tried to put the autorelease but I do not know if I'm doing it right. Could you write as it should be?

Comment: @IsraelMesquita Just send a `release` message when you're done with your controller and array (`[self.arrayOfTheAnotherView release];`). Apart from the memory management part, is it working now as expected?

Comment: yes I put it. But it don't work. I put too:
    self.superAnother.arrayOfTheAnotherView = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayOfTheCurrentView]autorelease];

Comment: [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayOfTheCurrentView]retain]; I used it too, don't work.

Comment: Maybe, you can help me, Can you give me some email to contact you?

Comment: @IsraelMesquita If you don't mind to upload your project somewhere on the web for download, I could have a look I guess...

Comment: Can I send a email with the project to you?